How to prevent the adjustment of the frame when cropping an image in react native?
How to prevent the adjustment of the frame when cropping an image with react-native-image-crop-picker. Specifically on iOS, I would like the framing to be fixed to width: 700 height: 1000  on iOS and not allow adjusting.
Here's the snippet below.

const _pickImage = () => {

  ImagePicker.openPicker({
    width: 700, 
    height: 1000, 
    cropping: true,
    cropperToolbarTitle: 'Adjust Image',
    cropperCircleOverlay: false, 
    freeStyleCropEnabled: false,
    hideBottomControls: false, 
    cropperActiveWidgetColor: '#00FF00', 
    cropperStatusBarColor: '#000', 
  })
    .then((image) => {
      setImage(image.path); // Save the selected image path
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.code !== 'E_PICKER_CANCELLED') {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'An error occurred while picking the image.');
      }
    });
};


